Как удалить из реестра ключи исключений для Windows Defender
В пользовательском интерфейсе Дефендера есть исключения, но удалить их оттуда не получается. Вот они в реестре:

Не могу никак удалить: сменить владельца не получается, разрешения для пользователей не меняются - вообще ничего с этими ключами не сделать в regedit.
Как их удалить?

Вопрос решился: есть еще одна ветка с этими исключениями:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Exclusions

Если попытасться из исключений Дефендера удалить эти исключения (безрезультатно!) - а потом удалить исключения к этой второй ветке - они исчезнут и там, откуда я их никакими силами не мог удалить. О как!
